# axios shows CORS error, with django rest framework

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

Thanks for reading.
I am working with vuejs SPA with flask and django backends. Yes there are 2 backends. The application is in transition. I am switching the back end from Flask to Django Rest Framework. Some parts are still with Flask.

**Problem**
axios POST request does not hit django server. The error in console shows as a CORS error. Same calls worked with `flask-restful` and `flask-CORS`.

GET request works fine with Django

> Relevant code

**BACKEND**

*settings.py*

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders'
   ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
...
```

*views.py*

```
...
class SnippetView(ListCreateView):
  queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
  serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

*urls.py*

```
...
  path('snippets/', SnippetListView.as_view(), name='snippet-list')
...
```

**FRONTEND** Vuejs

*component*

```
<template>
  <v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
  >
    <v-text-field
      v-model="code"
      label="Code"
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-text-field
      v-model="text"
      label="text"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

*axios*

```
  ...
  let snippet = { code: 'abc', text: ''} // comes from vuetifyjs form
  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/data/snippets', snippet)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data) // not working
  ...
```

Adding json data works normally in `django-admin dashboard`, `django_rest_framework API interface` and in `httpie` command line client

So it appears the issue is with axios.

I have tried

```
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

Above have been tried separately

I have also tried with fetch, which registers the post request with server but does not return a response

I still gets cors error. The request does not even reach the server.

I have also tried different CORS settings, whitelists as mentioned here https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

Comment: CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS used to be CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL. If you're using an older version, maybe replace CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS with CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL and try once

Comment: Have already done that. It did not work!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
This was due to some issue with axios
I updated axios to 0.21.x in vue cli and it started working